# Why are the fingertips not moving with my hand in pose mode?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

My armature moves but the fingertips on the hand are staying in place.  [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[image: recreated problem]

I belive I have recreated the problem with the image above

Check to see if the finger tips are **weight painted**. Weight painting controls how a model's mesh is manipulated whenever bones are moved. This means if a mesh is not painted correctly, you will get issues like part of the fingers not moving with the rest of the hand.

When in "Object" mode, select your armature, then also select your mesh which contains the fingertips

[image: weight paints example]

**Weight painting mode 101:**

- Single bone's weight paints can be viewed with ctrl and selecting that bone
- Multiple bone's weight paints can be viewed with shift and selcting multiple bones
- this mode will show a heatmap showing the weight of parts of the mesh
  - dark blue = weight 0.0 -> this part of mesh is not affected when the selected bone is moved/ will               stay in place no matter how the bone(s) are moved
  - dark red = weight 1.0 -> this part of mesh will completely move with the selected bone
- click on the mesh to paint on weights for certain bones

For more reading, here is the Blender Weight Painting Manual

So to fix the fingertips, you would select each of the bones at the tips of the fingers indivisually and paint the tops red with a brush with weight 1.0. This should make the fingertips snap into place as shown below.

[image: weight paints with one finger fixed]

Once you've done this with each finger and its respective bone, you should be able to go into pose mode and pose it however you want without the issue

[image: pose mode with issue resolved]

Hope this helps